# Setting intercept to zero: Will this change both standard deviations and the error term?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, variance, standard-deviation, intercept

After running a single regression with a forced zero intercept, I understand that $\beta$ (slope(s)) will change as $\alpha$ (intercept) will be set to zero. Easy.

$\rho = \beta(\sigma_x / \sigma_y)$ is left in question...

by way of....   $\beta =  \frac{\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)}{\mathrm{Var}(X)}$.....or......${\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)}=  \beta(\sigma_x^2)$

Given the forced change, will the $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ (std.devs) both remain as their non-forced original values, with $\rho$ (correlation) changing to match the new forced slope? What will happen to the error term given the forced zero regression?

Note: Calculations confirmed in Excel via using `StdevP` & `VarP` functions in small sample group.

Comment: I don't understand your notation $\rho_y$ and $\rho_y$. The formula you give should probably be meant $\beta_x = b_x(\sigma_x/\sigma_y)$. This formula of converting _b_ in _beta_ is valid also when there is no intercept; but then $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ must be standard deviations not from the _means_ but from 0, - they are _root mean squares_ then.

Comment: @ttnphns Please see edits for better clarification

Comment: It'd be nice to follow more standard notation: $b$ = regr. coef; $\beta$= standardized regr. coef; $r$ = empirical correlation etc.

Comment: Since none of $\sigma_x,$ $\sigma_y,$ or $\rho$ depend on this regression, the answer to the first question is trivial.  The only fully general answer to the second question must be "the mean squared error never goes down when the intercept is forced to be zero."